# How do I automate this repetitive task?

Tags: finder, automator

Automator would seem to the appropriative tool, but ehmac.ca is stumped and so has this board been so far — my "Automator Newbie" question asked yesterday (my first ever on this site). Two sticking points — changing the .tiff extension to .tif, and losing the Alpha option.

The problem to be solved is prepping a large collection of edited scanned text files in tif format and getting them ready for processing by the OCR app TesseractGUI 0.3. This OCR app balks at TIF files with an extension of .tiff, also balks at Alpha within the file format.

Here's the manual routine I've been using.

1. Open the file in Preview.
2. From the File menu choose the Export command.
3. Click in the file name field and delete the second "F".
4. Uncheck the Alpha option.
5. Click the Save button.
6. In the next dialogue choose the "Replace" option.
7. Close the window.
8. Rinse and repeat with the next file in the list.
9. Exit when all files have been prepped.

Appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This works in my tests and should give you a starting point.

I use two actions to get the folder and its contents.

- **Get Selected Finder Items**
- **Get Folder Contents**

---

Then using a '**Rename finder items**'  Action. I change the extension with it's settings set to:

***Replace Text***

*Find:* **tiff**  *in* **extension only**    -   ignore case **Yes**

*Replace:*  **tif**

---

Then a '**Run Shell Scrip**' Action  using the unix command [sips](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) I change the format of the files to jpeg and then back to tiff. This removes the alpha channel.

It's settings are :

- Shell: **/bin/bash**
- Pass input: **as Argument**

With the code:

```
for f in "$@"
do

 /usr/bin/sips -s format jpeg  "$f"; /usr/bin/sips -s format tiff  "$f"

done
```

---

[image]

To use I select the folder with the Images and run the workflow on it.
It will also work on a single  or multiple images if that is what is selected instead of a folder

---

Update.
User @chananelb  [pointed out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131470/17128) that the is an Automator Action that can change the file type. But since they did not put any instructions in how this could be done. I will add it here as an alternative option.

The input of the service stays the same. And the first action as discussed in the comments should be **Get Folder Contents**.

All other actions can be removed and two actions of **Change image type**  should be added.

The first **Change image type**  is set to jpeg.

The second is set to tiff.

Thats it simple.

[image]
[Open bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gysxL.png)

---

Comment: The concluding shell script fails with a "Contents not a valid file." The intent is to change tif into jpeg and then switch it back to tif in order to shack off the unwanted Alpha layer. I don't know Unix code. Can someone spot the error in the code?

Comment: I'm confused by Mark's concluding instruction: "To use I select the folder with the Images and run the workflow on it." What's the procedure to run a workflow on a selected folder? Appreciated.

Comment: The code worked on my test with no problems. I think I just selected the files and ran the workflow from automator but you can make it into service. I am sure I selected file that were not images to see if they broke it. But they did not. I am not in front of a computer at the mo. But will check it when I am.

Comment: I'm not only working out how to solve this particular problem, I'm also learning this radically different "solutions forum". Challenging because virtually all the usual UI chrome is unlabelled and the feedback loop (so far) is this comment box. I'm starting to like it but have a lot to learn (about stack exchange) before I'll be really comfortable, or even proficient.

Comment: I just made it a Automator service. By creating a service  with input files and folders and removing the 'Get Selected Finder Items' action which the service input replaces. Agin worked with no errors. So I am not sure what is going on when you run it. Can you please tell me how and what you are doing.

Comment: By the way do you know what a 'Service' is? in reference to Automator

Comment: The problem is mainly in how to apply the routine to the collection of Alpha-ed Tiffs, which is established in the very first decision — workflow, application, service or service. The other problem is me, myself — working without an Automator introductory guide. And secondarily with StackExchange, a radically different interface for seeking help with a problem. But I'm rapidly catching on to SE's interface and liking it. ;-) I'll rework it as a service as you suggest above.

Comment: Screenshots of work in progress is posted at "How do I add a script to the Service menu?"

Comment: @user77681 I have updated my answer