# How do I add a script to the Service menu?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, automator, services

See "How do I automate this repetitive task?" I'm posting here so I can show some screenshots of the work in progress. I'm very new to both StackExchange and also Automator. Don't yet know my way around and am stuck.

I'm told to create it as a Service. I start a new Automator file and choose the "Service" option.

[image: Automator screenshot]

[image: Another Automator screenshot]

Save and close the file using the name "ConvertTiffForOCR.workflow. I reopen the file and am given the option of installing it in the Services menu. I say yes to the install.

I go to the Finder's Services menu, choose my new script and nothing happens. No error messages.

Comment: Are your sure bash script is correct?  Does it work outside Automator like in a shell script.   If it runs since its just a bash script it wouldn't produce any output.

Comment: Yes the bash script is correct. It is from another question. This service is one I gave as an answer. The problem is the OP did not know about services. Hence this question. Once saved. The "ConvertTiffForOCR" will appear in the services contextual menu that appears when you right click on a files/folders. You do not need to open the workflow file directly. Automator should have already save the file to  the correct services folder in the user library. This workflow does not have any feed back when finished. Have you checked the files

Comment: Other question. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130185/how-do-i-automate-this-repetitive-task

Comment: You can use the `logger`command to get a bit more information. In the bash script, put in a `logger "$f"` in the loop body (between `do` and `done`). The output should show up in the Console App in */Applications/Utilities/*. Report back.

Comment: The collective help with this question is very much appreciated. However the question is not yet fully answered. Not yet able to put it to use. How is this routine able to identify the TIFFs to apply its routine to? When the Service is selected there is no action, nor any error reported.

Comment: @user77681 According to the "other question" referenced, you are forgetting the first step in the workflow: That being, "Get Selected Finder Items"

Comment: You select the files in finder and right click on them to see the services contextual menu. The Service (without the  "Get Selected Finder Items") will use the selected files of folder as it's input. ta. da..

Comment: No Action? So ADD an action that you can detect. Something like the script: **say "hello world"** That'll at least tell you whether the thing is running.

Comment: Hey, success! Although when the tif is opened with the Preview app's Export command it still shows as a tiff file format rather than as a tif. The main file format change is performed by changing the file into a jpeg then immediately back into a tif. This file format swap loses the Alpha layer, the block to OCR apps such as TesseractGUI 0.3 from processing the tif. I suspect the editing of the file extension is not necessary. Will simplify the routine later in the day and publish a complete solution with notes. More soon.

Answer (score 1):

While bash is cool, doesn't the image manipulation module in Automator accomplish what you are trying to achieve?

Instead of your last stage in the Automator workflow add the Photo Format module twice ( Automator Library>Photos>Change Type Of Images), the only option is target image type, where you'd presumably select jpeg for the first one and then tiff for the second one.

[This article in MacObserver](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how_to_batch_convert_and_resize_images_with_automator) explains how to use the module in general.

Comment: @chanaelb you make a good point and I have added it to the answer on the question about how to do the task with instructions